# Как переделать код?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать чтобы иконки были квадратные и без цифр,а с одной из 7 картинок,а конечный результат был одинаков?

```js
$(function() {
  function random(min, max, l) {
    var arr = [],
      m = [],
      n = 0;
    if (max - min < l - 1) return;
    for (var i = 0; i <= (max - min); i++) m[i] = i + min;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (m.length));
      arr[i] = m.splice(n, 1)[0];
    };
    return arr
  }


  var arr = random(0, 36, 37),
    carusel = $('#carusel');

  function rand(min, max, integer) {
    var r = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    return integer ? r | 0 : r;
  }

  $.each(arr, function(indx, el) {
    $('<li/>', {
      text: el,
      data: {
        i: el
      },
      css: {
        'background-color': el ? el % 2 ? 'red' : 'black' : 'green'
      },
      color: el ? 'white' : 'black'
    }).appendTo(carusel)
    carusel.width('+=60')
  });

  function lotto() {
    var n = rand(0, arr.length, true);

    r = rand(2, 5, true);

    carusel.stop();
    (function go() {
      carusel.animate({
        left: '-=50'
      }, 100, function() {
        var li = $('li:first');
        data = $('#carusel>li:eq(5)').data('i');
        if (data == n) r--;


        li.appendTo(carusel)
        carusel.css({
          left: '0px'
        });
        r && go();

        if (!r) {
          $('#carusel>li:eq(4)').css({
            "border": "#86B817 3px solid"
          });
        }
      })
    }())


  }
  $('[type="button"]').on({
    click: lotto
  })

})
```

```css
li {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#carusel {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.divv {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 540px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px
}

#carusel li {
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>

<div class="divv">
  <ul id="carusel">

  </ul>
</div>

<p></p>
<input name="" type="button" value="go">
```

```
https://jsfiddle.net/6jwo1csy/
```

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Иконки квадратные, свои картинки можешь поставить вместо bgc.
Еще поправил border-ы, после каждого спин-а они сбрасываются и не увеличивают размер li.

```js
$(function() {
  function random(min, max, l) {
    var arr = [],
      m = [],
      n = 0;
    if (max - min < l - 1) return;
    for (var i = 0; i <= (max - min); i++) m[i] = i + min;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (m.length));
      arr[i] = m.splice(n, 1)[0];
    };
    return arr
  }


  var arr = random(0, 7, 8),
    carusel = $('#carusel');

  function rand(min, max, integer) {
    var r = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    return integer ? r | 0 : r;
  }

  $.each(arr, function(indx, el) {
    $('<li/>', {
      text: el,
      data: {
        i: el
      },
      css: {
        'background': el == 0 ? 'green' : el == 1 ? 'red' : el == 2 ? 'pink' : el == 3 ? "purple" : el == 4 ? '#673ab7' : 
        el == 5 ? 'indigo' : el == 6 ? 'blue' : 'orange' //  меняй тут цвета на свои картинки //
      },
      color: el ? 'white' : 'black',
      text: ''
    }).appendTo(carusel)
    carusel.width('+=60')

  });





/*------SPINER------*/
  function lotto() {
    $('#carusel>li:eq(4)').css({
            "border": 'none'
          });

    var n = rand(0, arr.length, true);

    r = rand(2, 5, true);

    carusel.stop();
    (function go() {
      carusel.animate({
        left: '-=50'
      }, 100, function() {
        var li = $('li:first');
        data = $('#carusel>li:eq(5)').data('i');
        if (data == n) r--;


        li.appendTo(carusel)
        carusel.css({
          left: '0px'
        });
        r && go();

        if (!r) {
          $('#carusel>li:eq(4)').css({
            "border": "#86B817 3px solid"
          });
        }
      })
    }())


  }
  $('[type="button"]').on({
    click: lotto
  })

})
```

```css
li {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#carusel {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.divv {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 304px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px
}

#carusel li {
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="powerange.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>

    <div class="divv">
      <ul id="carusel">
      </ul>
    </div>

    <p></p>
    <input name="" type="button" value="go">
 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="powerange.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое)

Comment: Рад был помочь!